# A complex number $z_1$ is unimodular. If $\frac{z_1-2z_2}{2-z_1\bar z_2}$ is unimodular, and $z_2$ is not unimodular, then prove that....

Tags: complex-numbers

> A complex number $z_1$ is unimodular. If $\frac{z_1-2z_2}{2-z_1\bar z_2}$ is unimodular, and $z_2$ is not unimodular, then prove that $z_2$ lies on a circle of radius 2.

Since the given expression is unimodular

$$|z_1-2z_2|=|2-z_1\bar z_2|$$

Which is the same as

$$|z_1-2z_2|=|2-\bar z_1z_2|$$

Since conjugates inside a modulus are equal

So 
$$|z_1-2z_2|=|2-\frac{z_2}{z_1}|$$

$$|z_1-2z_2|=|2z_1-z_2|$$

What should I do next?

Comment: The acclaimed result is not true. Check, if $z_1=1; z_2=2$ but from $w=\frac{z_1-2z_2}{2-z_1 \bar z_2}\implies |w|=\infty.$ You may see my Answer posted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a contradiction. From the given $|z_1-2z_2|=|2-z_1\bar z_2|$, we have

$$(z_1-2z_2)(\bar z_1-2\bar z_2 )
=(2-z_1\bar z_2)(2-\bar z_1 z_2) $$

which leads to

$$(|z_1|^2-4)(|z_2|^2-1)=0$$

So, if $z_2$ is not unimodular, $|z_1|^2=4$, which means $z_1$ lies on a circle of radius 2.

Comment: Yes, I am now sure that there is a problem with the question itself.

Comment: @Quanto The acclaimed result is not true. Check, if $z_1=1; z_2=2$ but from $w=\frac{z_1-2z_2}{2-z_1 \bar z_2}\implies |w|=\infty.$ You may see my Answer posted now.

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc - I expressed the same at the start

Comment: @Quanto Yes I now see that, you too were right. cheers

Answer (score 0):

The acclaimed result is^ ** not true**. Check, if $z_1=1; z_2=2$ but if $$w=\frac{z_1-2z_2}{2-z_1 \bar z_2}\implies |w|=\infty.$$
**OP's approach is correct** then further to his last eq. we get
$$|z_1-2z_2|^2=|2z_1-z_2|^2 \implies (z_1 -2 z_2)(\bar z_1-2\bar z_2)=(2z_1-z_2)(2\bar z_1-\bar z_2)\implies -3|z_1|^2+3 |z_2|^2=0 \implies
|z_1|=|z_2|$$ 
and since $|z_1|=1$ hence $$|z_2|=1$$